# How would one find listings of names on ledger stones in English cathedrals?

Tags: england, sources

I had several trips to UK 25 to 50 years ago. I once saw my surname on a few ledger stones in a main corridor of an English cathedral. But now I can not remember which one. I thought it was Winchester but I got a reply from that staff that it was not there. Is there a general source for such information ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is any use- but at least it has potential.

http://www.buildingconservation.com/articles/ledger-stones/ledger-stones.htm

it has got a link to this

www.lsew.org.uk

a site doing surveys on such things.

I think they have  some sort of register that you may be able to download. I tried earlier - but it didn't load.

further too this :-

this might be useful for those looking for grave(stone)s - it uses ancestry sometimes - but it may be seperate?

https://www.findagrave.com/

I did another bit of investigation and this site could be of interest to a lot of people

http://cmsgazetteer.co.uk/

it describes itself as a gazetteer which sets out to list the monuments in cathedrals, churches, chapels, museums and even streets and private houses in Britain and France; there are also a few listed from other parts of Europe.